# Extract CDATA tagged values from .kml in R

Tags: r, kml

I'd like to extract from a .kml file the value(s) for description using R.

Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <Document>
 <open>1</open>
 <visibility>1</visibility>
 <name><![CDATA[2013-07-06 4:18pm]]></name>
 ...
 <Placemark>
 <name><![CDATA[2013-07-06 4:18pm (Start)]]></name>
 <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
 <TimeStamp><when>2013-07-06T20:18:56.000Z</when></TimeStamp>
 <styleUrl>#start</styleUrl>
 <Point>
 <coordinates>-78.353348,45.020615,340.29998779296875</coordinates>
 </Point>
 </Placemark>
 <Placemark id="tour">
 <name><![CDATA[2013-07-06 4:18pm]]></name>
 <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
 ...
 <gx:Track>
 <when>2013-07-06T20:18:56.000Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-78.353348 45.020615 340.29998779296875</gx:coord>
 <when>2013-07-06T20:19:12.000Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-78.353315 45.020644 340.29998779296875</gx:coord>
 <when>2013-07-06T22:12:23.000Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-78.353108 45.020736 342.29998779296875</gx:coord>
 <ExtendedData>
  ...
  <Placemark>
  <name><![CDATA[2013-07-06 4:18pm (End)]]></name>
  <description><![CDATA[Created by Google My Tracks on Android.

  Name: 2013-07-06 4:18pm
  Activity type: cycling
  Description: -
  Total distance: 49.62 km (30.8 mi)
  Total time: 1:53:28
  Moving time: 1:50:17
  Average speed: 26.24 km/h (16.3 mi/h)
  Average moving speed: 27.00 km/h (16.8 mi/h)
 Max speed: 61.20 km/h (38.0 mi/h)
 Average pace: 2.29 min/km (3.7 min/mi)
 Average moving pace: 2.22 min/km (3.6 min/mi)
 Fastest pace: 0.98 min/km (1.6 min/mi)
 Max elevation: 406 m (1333 ft)
 Min elevation: 265 m (868 ft)
 Elevation gain: 690 m (2263 ft)
 Max grade: 12 %
 Min grade: -11 %
 Recorded: 2013-07-06 4:18pm
  ]]></description>
 ...
 </Placemark>
 </Document>
 </kml>
```

And here is what I want to extract, the text contained in

```
 <description><![CDATA[Created by Google My Tracks on Android.: ]]></description>
```

i.e.:

```
  Name: 2013-07-06 4:18pm
  Activity type: cycling
  Description: -
  Total distance: 49.62 km (30.8 mi)
  Total time: 1:53:28
  Moving time: 1:50:17
  Average speed: 26.24 km/h (16.3 mi/h)
  Average moving speed: 27.00 km/h (16.8 mi/h)
 Max speed: 61.20 km/h (38.0 mi/h)
 Average pace: 2.29 min/km (3.7 min/mi)
 Average moving pace: 2.22 min/km (3.6 min/mi)
 Fastest pace: 0.98 min/km (1.6 min/mi)
 Max elevation: 406 m (1333 ft)
 Min elevation: 265 m (868 ft)
 Elevation gain: 690 m (2263 ft)
 Max grade: 12 %
 Min grade: -11 %
 Recorded: 2013-07-06 4:18p
```

xmlToList gives me, I think NULL because the CDATA tag means the stuff following is not processed by the parser:

```
xml <- xmlTreeParse("test1.kml", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
xmllist <- xmlToList(xml)
xmllist$Document$Placemark$description
[[1]]
NULL
```

I think that is what [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) means "The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser ...Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser. A CDATA section starts with "" "

The following will not work for me either, perhaps for the same reason related to CDATA:

```
z1 <- xpathApply(xml, "//description", xmlValue)
z1
list()
```

Can anyone help me extract the text in the file?

Here is a link to the file: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B__iOdFGJbXYOHJGbWJVNW0tS3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you should give an a well formatted XML.

Comment: Link to .kml posed as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake Burkhead answered this in the comments. His solution does it. And I am most grateful. Here is how the text is extracted from the .kml file:

```
> xml1 <- xmlTreeParse("2013-07-06 4-18pm.kml", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
> root <-xmlRoot(xml1)
> names(root[["Document"]])
  open   visibility         name       author        Style        Style        Style        Style 
  "open" "visibility"       "name"     "author"      "Style"      "Style"      "Style"      "Style" 
   Style       Schema    Placemark    Placemark    Placemark 
 "Style"     "Schema"  "Placemark"  "Placemark"  "Placemark" 
> # note that I want the text in the third "Placemark" which is in position [13] so:
> xmlValue(root[["Document"]][[13]][["description"]])
 [1] "Created by Google My Tracks on Android.\n\nName: 2013-07-06 4:18pm\nActivity type:          cycling\nDescription: -\nTotal distance: 49.62 km (30.8 mi)\nTotal time: 1:53:28\nMoving time: 1:50:17\nAverage speed: 26.24 km/h (16.3 mi/h)\nAverage moving speed: 27.00 km/h (16.8 mi/h)\nMax speed: 61.20 km/h (38.0 mi/h)\nAverage pace: 2.29 min/km (3.7 min/mi)\nAverage moving pace: 2.22 min/km (3.6 min/mi)\nFastest pace: 0.98 min/km (1.6 min/mi)\nMax elevation: 406 m (1333 ft)\nMin elevation: 265 m (868 ft)\nElevation gain: 690 m (2263 ft)\nMax grade: 12 %\nMin grade: -11 %\nRecorded: 2013-07-06 4:18pm\n"
```

I have accepted the answer but thought I put the complete solution here in case it helps others.

Many thanks for your persistence Jake. Thanks also Ricardo and agstudy.

Answer (score 3):

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("test1.kml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
root <-xmlRoot(doc)

xmlValue(root[["Document"]][["name"]])

R> xmlValue(root[["Document"]][["name"]])
 [1] "2013-07-06 4:18pm"
```

Also `xmlToDataFrame(root)` and `xmlToDataFrame(doc)` return that value in the name column. Using `xmlToList` on either root or doc returns `NULL` for the value of any CData. I'm looking at the name node because copy and pasting your example doesn't `xmlParse`. From my own little tests it looks like this should work on any CData.

Comment: This has promise but I am not sure of the syntax I need to get the CDATA tagged data out. xmlValue(root[["Document"]][["description"]])
gives NA. As does xmlValue(root[["Document"]][["CDATA"]]).

Comment: @user172665 Can you show the output of `root[[Document"]][["description"]]`? Or put the entire, well-formatted XML. It's now starting to sound like you're improperly finding the node. also look at `names(root)` and names `root[["Description"]]` etc.

Comment: second description should be lower case

Comment: Jake: root[[Document"]][["description"]] gives NA

Comment: and names(root[["description"]]) gives NULL

Comment: @user172665 my mistake. `names(root[["description"]])` should be `NULL` since the root node has no children named `"description"`. I should have said `names(root["Document"]])`. `root` is like a named list where each element is a child node and also a named list with its children nodes, etc. You can navigate through nodes like that. I would suggest looking at `names` of each node starting from the root to get to where ever you want. It looks like it might actually be within the `Placemark` node and even the `ExtendedData` node Properly formatted xml would help.

Comment: names(root[["Document"]])
        open   visibility         name       author        Style        Style        Style        Style 
      "open" "visibility"       "name"     "author"      "Style"      "Style"      "Style"      "Style" 
       Style       Schema    Placemark 
     "Style"     "Schema"  "Placemark"

Comment: Here is a link to the file: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B__iOdFGJbXYOHJGbWJVNW0tS3M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user172665 `xmlValue(root[["Document"]][[13]][["description"]])` works for me. It seems to be having trouble since there are multiple children of the Document node named Placemark.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jake. Much appreciated. I was able to extract it as you suggested. names(root[["Document"]]) gets the names and then counting along to get where the Placemake is (in my example it was 13) I can get the text with xmlValue(root[["Document"]][[13]][["description"]])

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution to this problem is to read in the data using the `xml2` package.

```
# Instead of xmlTreeParse
read_xml("test1.kml", options = "NOCDATA")
```

Then you can simply retrieve the CDATA with `xml_text()`.

```
# Instead of xmllist$Document$Placemark$description
read_xml("test1.kml", options = "NOCDATA") %>%
   xml_nodes("Placemark") %>% 
   xml_nodes("description") %>% 
   xml_text()
```