# How to get data I need from CDATA part using R

Tags: r, cdata

Now I have to get some data I need from a XML file. The data is in the CDATA part which is painful to get.
The data is in the format as followings:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Calc>
   <MarketData>
      <![CDATA[Interestrate.CHF,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,Currency=CHF,
       curve=[(1,0.1),(2,0.1)...(15,0.1)] Interestrate.EUR,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,
       Currency=EUR,curve=[...] InterestRateVol.CHF,Type=,LongRunMean=0.01,..]]>
   </MarketData>
   <Calendars>.....
   </Calendars>
</Calc>
```

Like I want to get the curve data of Interestrate.EUR. How should I do it in R?
Need I have to locate "Interestrate.EUR" first, then grab the data after first "curve".
Any good suggestion to deal with the CDATA? Or any other language can work out this problem.

Comment: Use the xml package for parsing (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540262/extract-cdata-tagged-values-from-kml-in-r). Then perhabs some regex to grab curve format it to a data.frame.

Comment: @EDi i check that answer before, however, the "names(root(..))"give me null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xData <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Calc>
  <MarketData>
  <![CDATA[Interestrate.CHF,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,Currency=CHF,
           curve=[(1,0.1),(2,0.1)...(15,0.1)] Interestrate.EUR,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,
           Currency=EUR,curve=[...] InterestRateVol.CHF,Type=,LongRunMean=0.01,..]]>
  </MarketData>
  <Calendars>.....
</Calendars>
  </Calc>'
library(XML)
xData <- xmlParse(xData)
cData <- xpathSApply(xData, "//text()", xmlValue)
> cData[1]
[1] "Interestrate.CHF,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,Currency=CHF,\n           curve=[(1,0.1),(2,0.1)...(15,0.1)] Interestrate.EUR,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,\n           Currency=EUR,curve=[...] InterestRateVol.CHF,Type=,LongRunMean=0.01,.."


out <- strsplit(cData[1], ' ')[[1]] 

> out[out != ""]
[1] "Interestrate.CHF,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,Currency=CHF,\n"
[2] "curve=[(1,0.1),(2,0.1)...(15,0.1)]"                      
[3] "Interestrate.EUR,Type=,Floor=<undefined>,\n"             
[4] "Currency=EUR,curve=[...]"                                
[5] "InterestRateVol.CHF,Type=,LongRunMean=0.01,.."
```

Comment: hey, thank you for answering! What you posted is very helpful. Actually, after I get the whole CDATA part, the problem is that how can I get the specific content I needed from these CDATA part. Like I only need the second curve data in these CDATA, any suggetion? :)

Comment: @Louisyan can you give a complete example `XML`. The `CDATA` can have any format.

Comment: I have edit the question with the complete XML structure. Thank you

Comment: @Louisyan I have ammended my answer using your example. `cData[1]` contains the `CDATA` you are interested in.

Comment: thank you jdharrison.The problem is that If I only want to get the second curve data, not all the CDATA part. What should I do, any method to locate and grab the data I need? For example, I only need the "Interestrate.EUR, curve=[..]" the data in [..].

Comment: @Louisyan I have added a `strsplit` statement that should enable you to get the content you require.

Comment: Thank you! It works! BTW, can I ask if I want to inquire in the "out" to locate the "Interestrate.CHF" which function should I use?

Comment: I tried using "pmatch" to get the locate of string, it works. Thank you